# how to implement RSS reader (For news ) in my app?

Tags: android, rss

i want to implement a RSS reader in my app i want to display the news in listview along with the respective image.

**Main Activity**

```
    package piestudio.opinion;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.toi) {


             fragment = new FragmentOne();
             FragmentTransaction ft= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,"Times of India");
            ft.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.thehindu) {

            } else if (id == R.id.support) {



            }
    return  true;
    }

        }
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
    package piestudio.opinion;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by jene on 7/4/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {



    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

Fragment One is the fragment where i want my list view to be displayed please guide me in detail like what layout is to be be made and i have also created 
RSSfeed class. i have searched on various sites but did not find any relevant answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Post your RSSfeed class, because nobody can know what you have implemented so far.

You basically want to download data from internet. You will need to download asynchronously on another thread not to block UI thread (Avoid freezing of UI). Use AsyncTask class to achieve that. Many examples of using AsyncTask can be found here.

Next step would be to parse downloaded XML. You can use different classes to do that. I would follow the official Android [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).

When you are done with parsing the needed feed, you just need to display it. I'd go with ListView, but thats entirely your choice.

That is the way to implement it yourself, which i recommend, since you learn how this stuff works. On the other hand you can use some [library](https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library)

Best way would be (for begginer) to implement it yourself, while looking to the library source code.